# Переместить папку с SSD на HDD через symlink

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hdd, ssd

Имеем сервер с двумя дисками SSD 240Gb и HDD 1024Gb
На SSD расположен сайт, имеющий временную папку temp, которая в процессе работы занимает много места (<100Gb), что негативно сказывается на работе сайта - кроме нее имеется достаточно большая база MySQL, и периодически возникает ошибка "Недостаточно места на диске".
Сейчас нужно перенести конкретно эту папку на другой диск.
Хотел сделать это просто поменяв путь к папке в скриптах, но проблема в том что к некоторым файлам из этой папки в процессе работы нужны рабочие ссылки вида сайт.ру/temp/мой.файл , в случае с физическим переносом такие ссылки на другой диск дать не получится.

Смотрю в сторону symlink ("подменить" папку), но никак не разберусь что именно нужно сделать. Возможно, как то можно "монтировать" эту папку на другой диск, но не разберусь вдвойне.. (

Прошу вашей помощи, друзья..

Answer (score 0):

Стопим сервис, который дёргает папку:

```
service httpd stop
```

Перемещаем папку на новое место:

```
mv /path/to/mysite/on/hdd /path/to/dir/on/ssd
```

Создаём симлинк нового пути на старый:

```
ln -s /path/to/dir/on/ssd /path/to/mysite/on/hdd
```

Запускаем сервис обратно:

```
service httpd start
```

Но я бы на твоём месте, прежде чем делать это на проде - поиграл бы как с симлинками отдельно - до полного понимания как это пашет и до поднятия копии сайта с переносом папок там.